# Regarding overwriting data in a while loop

Tags: c#, list

I'm having a problem outputting to a WebGrid because my list gets overwritten, so by the end, I have the final line of data written for every line on the grid. I have to use a while loop because the data is continually being added to, and we're looking at alot of data, so I'm trying not to write to another list.

```
public class ChemData
{
    string strSQLconnection = "Server=Server;Database=data;Uid=Username;Pwd=Password";

    public int productId { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }

    public List<ProdData> ProdList = new List<ProdData>();

    public List<ProdData> ProdDataPull()
    {
        ProdData Analysis = new ProdData();
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select * from producttable");

        conn.Open();
        query.Connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
        query.Connection.Open();
        reader = query.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) Analysis.productId = reader.GetInt32(0);
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1)) Analysis.productName = reader.GetString(1);

            ProdList.Add(Analysis);
         } 
         return ChemList;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a web grid to continually list items as they get added?  For that you would probably need some fancy AJAX...

Comment: Please update your post with all of the `while` loop.  You seem to be missing a closing brace (if not more).

Comment: Well, the code that you post is incompleted..right? can you post the completed one?

Comment: I'm trying to write everything in that SQL query into one list

Comment: iswantoSan posting full code is not his problem. the issues is he's not creating a new instance of `ProdData Analysis = new ProdData();` inside the while loop for starters. and he does have the full code posted can you see the `;}}` it's just not formatted the way that you are use to seeing

Comment: Couldn't fit it all in there. It turned out to be what you said though, i needed to create a new instance inside the while loop. Thanks guys.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - the closing braces were added later as an edit.  The original post was missing them.  Agreed that his problem is having only a single instance in the works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Analysis` is created only once.  Adding it to the list each time adds a reference to the same object.  Moving the creation to inside the while loop should fix this

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ProdData Analysis = new ProdData();
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) Analysis.productId = reader.GetInt32(0);
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(1)) Analysis.productName = reader.GetString(1);

    ProdList.Add(Analysis);
}
```

This creates a new `ProdData` object on each iteration of the loop and assigns it to `Analysis`, then updates its contents and adds that reference to the list.

With the creation of `Analysis` outside the loop `Analysis` continues to point to the same `ProdData` object that gets added over and over to the list while its values are overwritten each time.

See : [Reference Types vs. Value Types](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types#Value%20types%20and%20reference%20types)